# Math in Django ORM and SQLite: decimal ignored if round number, correct result if not round

Tags: python, django, django-orm

In a complex query, I have an annotate like this one:

```
result.annotate(test=ExpressionWrapper(485.00 / F( 'period_duration' ), 
output_field=DecimalField()))
```

This gives me the correct result:

```
Decimal('8.01917989417989E-10')
```

However, if I replace `485.00` with `485`:

```
result.annotate(test=ExpressionWrapper( 485 / F( 'period_duration' ),
output_field=DecimalField()))
```

I get:

```
Decimal('0')
```

This wouldn't be a problem, if it wasn't that 485 also comes from a field, called "`value`". My query looks like this:

```
result.annotate(test=ExpressionWrapper( F( 'value' ) / F( 'period_duration' ),
output_field=DecimalField()))
```

Value is a [MoneyField](https://pypi.org/project/django-moneyfield/), basically just a fancy wrapper around DecimalField.

I can force my users to always use proper decimals (`485.00` as opposed to `485`), which in itself would be bad design but... even then, if the database value is `485.00`, Django behaves as if it is `485` and thus returns `0` while doing floating point math.

I have tried `Cast`ing value to a `DecimalField`, to no avail.

```
result.annotate( res=ExpressionWrapper(
Cast('value', output_field=DecimalField()) / F( 'period_duration' ),
output_field=DecimalField() )).last().res
```

Result is always:

```
Decimal('0')
```

Instead of the correct one:

```
Decimal('8.01917989417989E-10')
```

How can I force Django to always use floating point math?

p.s. `period_duration` is `604800000000`, if it's of any help.

Comment: You should look at (and edit into your question) the actual SQL query generated here. `print(queryset.query)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `F( 'value' )` is giving you a number?

MoneyField stores your attribute *value* in two columns, so `F( 'value' )` might not be what you expect.

Maybe try `F( 'value_amount' )`.

Comment: Yes, it gives a number. value_amount returns error. value.amount is only in Python, at the database level there’s only value and value_currency.